# Using tensorflow.argmax on a tensorflow.placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow

Why does `tf.reduce_sum()` work on a `tf.placeholder` while `tf.argmax()` can't, even though both accept as an input a `Tensor` and return a `Tensor`?

The following piece of code works normally:

```py
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10])
y = tf.reduce_sum(x)
sess = tf.Session()
session.run(y, {x: np.arange(10)})
```

While this one (using `tf.argmax()` instead) doesn't:

```py
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10])
y = tf.argmax(x)
sess = tf.Session()
session.run(y, {x: np.arange(10)})
```

And returns the following error (in the `y= tf.argmax(x)` call):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 490, in apply_op
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 669, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 176, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 165, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 360, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 249, in argmax
    return gen_math_ops.arg_max(input, axis, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 168, in arg_max
    name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 503, in apply_op
    as_ref=input_arg.is_ref).dtype.name
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 669, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 176, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 165, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 360, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Comment: This seems like a bug in `tf.argmax` implementation. Use `tf.argmax(x, axis=0)` as a temporary workaround.

Comment: @keveman Indeed that was the problem.

Comment: keveman .. thanks for the comment, why don't you add that in answer section - it's perfect.